# VK API получить ссылку на оригинальное видео

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Бот, который подключен к группе в ВК получает callback запросы, которые вызваны пользователем, который кидает ссылку вида `youtube.com/watch***` (ссылка на видео с ютуба). Но вк отправляет боту только объект video, ссылка удаляется. Как я могу получить оригинальную ссылку? Есть ключ доступа только группы, т.е нельзя получить ссылку через метод `video.get`

Answer (score 0):

Пока что единственный вариант это использовать пользовательский ключ и вызывать video.get с ним. То есть собирать объекты видосов и раз в секунду вызывать метод с пачкой в поле videos.

В будущем ключ сообщества научится этому методу.

Comment: А в каком будущем он может научиться этому? И у меня почему-то не получается вызвать videg.get() от имени другого пользователя, даже с использованием access_key

Comment: @vladF  Ни в каком. Уже 2023 год на дворе, а он всё ещё не научился.